# Nodes aren't toggling with toggle()

Tags: jquery

My HTML structure is as follows. I am trying to expand and collapse each node with icon.

```
    <div id="content">
  <h2>Celebs</h2>
    <ul id="celebTree">
      <li>A-list Celebrities
        <ul>
          <li>In a successful band
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Johnny Stardust</a></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Glendatronix</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
          <li>In an indie band
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#">Computadors</a></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#">The Great Apes</a></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#">Bosom</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
          <li>In film or television
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#">Kelly Kellie</a></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#">Amelia Austin</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Famous because they're rich
        <ul>
          <li>Famous parents
            <ul>
              <li>Vienna Sheraton</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Dot-Com millionaires
            <ul>
              <li>Joel Mynor</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I am using this code to toggle

```
$('#celebTree ul')
    .hide()
    .before('<span></span>')
    .prev()
    .addClass('handle closed')
    .click(function() {
      $(this)
        .toggleClass('closed opened')
        .nextAll('ul')
        .toggle();
});
```

However none of my nodes open. What am i doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/zvopye7z/

Comment: hidden? How is it hidden? The list starts in a collapsed state

Comment: You're binding the click handlers to those empty spans that you added with `.before("<span>")`. Since they're empty, there's nothing to click on.

Comment: Ok. can you show me how to fix the code please?

Comment: Your `<span>` is empty, so there's nothing to be clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your spans are empty, there's nothing to click on. You can use CSS to display something to click on:

```
.closed:before {
    content: "+";
}
.opened:before {
    content: "-";
}
```

You can also use the `width` property, as in Jack's answer, to set them off from the adjacent text.

```
.handle { 
    background: transparent url( tree-handle.png ) no-repeat left top; 
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 1em;
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```js
$('#celebTree ul')
  .hide()
  .before('<span></span>')
  .prev()
  .addClass('handle closed')
  .click(function() {
    $(this)
      .toggleClass('closed opened')
      .nextAll('ul')
      .toggle();
  });
```

```css
#celebTree,
#celebTree ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
.handle {
  background: transparent url(tree-handle.png ) no-repeat left top;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1em;
}
.closed {
  background-position: left top;
}
.closed:before {
  content: "+";
}
.opened {
  background-position: left -10px;
}
.opened:before {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h2>Celebs</h2>
  <ul id="celebTree">
    <li>A-list Celebrities
      <ul>
        <li>In a successful band
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Johnny Stardust</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Glendatronix</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>In an indie band
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Computadors</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">The Great Apes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Bosom</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>In film or television
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Kelly Kellie</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Amelia Austin</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Famous because they're rich
          <ul>
            <li>Famous parents
              <ul>
                <li>Vienna Sheraton</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Dot-Com millionaires
              <ul>
                <li>Joel Mynor</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>B-list Celebrities
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Mo' Fat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Darth Fader</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Up and Comers
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Mr Speaker</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">The jQuery Ninja</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that the <span> is showing after the textnode. How to add it before the Textnode

Comment: I see it before the text, e.g. `+ A-list Celebrities`.

Comment: Yes but if you inspect its markup, it is after the textnode

Comment: It's right before the `<ul>`, where you put it with `.before("<span></span>")`. So that puts it between the textnode and the `<ul>`.

Comment: Looks like the `float: left` property is causing it to display in the proper place.

Comment: yes but is there a way I can place it before the textnodes?

Comment: Maybe `.parent().prepend("<span>")`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<span>` is empty, so without specifying any width or height it won't occupy anything on the page; the styles that were applied to it only specified a background image and block display type.

To illustrate, adding these two styles to `.handle` will make them show up:

```
width:2em;
height:1em;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zvopye7z/4/)

Comment: One more point. Using Inspectelement I found that the <span> is showing after the textnode. How to add it before the Textnode.

Comment: @Hitz It shows in the right spot, so why bother? :)